# Strange behaviour in Neural Network training?

Tags: neural-network, classification, email-spam

I have created a neural network for detection spam.
It involves the following steps;

```
1.Formation of tf-idf matrix of terms and mails.
2.Reduction of matrix using PCA.
3.Feeding the 20 most important terms according to eigen values to neural network as features.
```

I'm training it for 1-Spam and 0-Not spam.

EDITS:
I decided to train it by taking a batch size of 7 mails because it was prone to showing Out of  memory error while forming the matrix. I used the standard enron dataset of ham and spam .
I used to train neural network via back-propagation -1 input - 1 hidden - 1 output layer with 20 neurons in first layer and 6 hidden layer neurons.

So I started training with my original spam mails in my gmail giving very bad results before switching it to enron dataset. Satisfactory outputs were obtained after training quite a lot.

6 out of 14 mails were being detected spam when i tested.

I used alternative training like batch 1 of spam mails and batch 2 for ham mail and so on such that the network is trained for 1 output for spam and 0 for ham .

But now after too much training almost 400-500 mails i guess, it if giving bad results again . I reduced learning rate but no help.
What's going wrong?

Comment: You aren't giving us much information here.

Comment: I edited . Please tell me if you require some specific information.I'm very stuck. Thanks

Comment: For a smaller number of epochs, does it give you the results you are expecting? If so, your dataset is too small/biased or the network is overtrained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: It was !! Yes it is overtrained i guess! I'm training it all over again now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize my comments into an answer... If you're net is producing results that you would expect and then after additional training the output is less accurate, then there is a good chance it is [overtrained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

This is especially prone to happen if your data set is small or doesn't vary enough. Finding the optimal number of epochs is mostly trial-and-error.

Comment: Oh Right ! Thanks for the clarity ! Right now the condition I'm taking 1000 epochs..Should i vary it?

Comment: @IDK Try different amounts and compare them. You will really be able to see the impact if you graph 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000. Those should give you a wide range of accuracies.